# Is it possible to rotate a fan by splitting the phases by 100 degrees?

Tags: motor, fan

I have learnt, a motor can rotate only when the main and auxiliary windings are at 90 degrees phase shift.but is it possible to rotate it in between 90 and 120 degrees.

Comment: It is possible to have coils at any angle as long as the alternating current have  two fluxes that interact between stator+rotor. The more poles per rev, the lower the rotational frequency , RPM = f[Hz]  / poles *60 RPM/s for AC motors.

Answer (score 1):

Where a motor is designed to use 90 degrees phase shift between main and aux windings, that phase shift will result in the maximum starting torque.

Any phase shift will result in some torque. The cosine of the phase shift would be a good approximation to the resultant torque, so if 90 degrees was 100%, even 120 degrees would be 86% of maximum.